# Simulink missing library on linux

Tags: linux, matlab, simulink

I have to run a simulation in Simulink but on Linux I can't find a necessary block that I have on Simulink in Windows.

The missing block is: [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/xpc/io_ref/bytepacking.html?searchHighlight=Byte%20Packing&s_tid=doc_srchtitle). I don't know why on linux I can't find the simulink real-time library.

Moreover, the library is missing also during the installation.